# Doctrine findBy() calling method from entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need little help to call method from entity.

Here is the code I had try to execute.

```
$datat = $this->getDoctrine()  
->getRepository('AppBundle:users')  
->findBy(array('userId' => $userId));
```

after this, when I call

```
$data->getUser();
```

I get message about exeption "Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object"

When I dump $data I got data from table or if I execute
`->find()` with ID value.

Comment: `$datat` != `$data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findBy` returns generally an ArrayCollection.

You should use `findOneBy` instead in order to target only one entity...

So :

```
$datat = $this->getDoctrine()  
   ->getRepository('AppBundle:users')  
   ->findOneBy(array('userId' => $userId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method getUser() doesn't exist in users entity.

Just iterate over your `$datat` and called method from user object like that

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  // $user is an instance of users
 echo $user->getName(); //if this method exist in your entity model
}
```